# Google Calendar API - How To Create Service

Tags: java, android, google-calendar-api

Looking at the Google Calendar API v3 documentation, I see them show under Events.list this snippet of code.

```
String pageToken = null;
do {
  events = service.events().list('primary').setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
  List<Event> items = events.getItems();
  for (Event event : items) {
    System.out.println(event.getSummary());
  }
  pageToken = events.getNextPageToken();
} while (pageToken != null);
```

I am wondering how a person would go about setting up the "service" that is in the line

```
events = service.events().list('primary').setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
```

I think it might be

```
Calendar service = Calendar(httptransport, jsonfactory, httprequestinitializer)
```

but am not 100% sure so I am asking for help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a code for the web based calendar thing, you might need web services for this to run on android.

Comment: I have enabled GMS services already, I think it is something else.